# Differences between mWm-2sr-1(cm-1)-1 and W/m^2 * sr * um

Tags: remote-sensing, solar-radiation, toa-calibration, reflectance

I'm confused about the use of this quantity. For example [eumetsat](https://www.eumetsat.int/website/wcm/idc/idcplg?IdcService=GET_FILE&dDocName=PDF_TEN_05105_MSG_IMG_DATA&RevisionSelectionMethod=LatestReleased&Rendition=Web)

on pag. 16 radiance is equal to:

> Physical Units = Cal_Offset + (Cal_Slope x Level 1.5 Pixel Count)

expressed in **mWm-2 sr-1 (cm-1)-1**

and table in page 20 represents dynamic range in **W/m^2*sr*um** unit.

The question is: when I read seviri spectral channel from MSG2/3 and after the transformation above, do I have values expressed in first or second units?

Answer (score 1):

They are not using uniform units. The first is using mW (miliwatts) for power and cm (centimeters) for wavelength, and the latter W (watts) for power and um (micrometers) for wavelength.

You can convert between the two using the conversion factors for both: 1 mW = 10^-3 W and 1 um = 10^-6 m.

According to the documentation, in 3.1.7, I would guess that the representation uses the first convention you mention. You could use the theoretical properties of a known target/surface/material to confirm.